# Where can I ask questions regarding Unix programming?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation, scope

I have some doubts regarding Unix programming, and I didn't find any particular tag to ask Unix-based questions on Stack Overflow.

Can anyone suggest to me where I can ask questions regarding Unix-based programming?

Comment: could you elaborate on what unix programming problem youre trying to solve... I find unix specific answers all day long on SO.  As a starting point, perhaps you could browse the linux tag

Comment: @downvoter can you please comment on downvoting?

Comment: iam beginner and trying to grep the .out files, but as the grepped content seemed to be present in more lines and its keeps on moving the screen and i am unable to find particular line. so if i can grep those lines to another file . i can search it page by page.

Comment: dandomar, if you are having problems with your grep scrolling off the screen, pipe into 'less'... i.e. 'grep foo *.out | less'... remember , less is more :)

Comment: fyi, your problem is not a programming problem... it is a unix tools problem with grep.  The unix and linux site is a good place to ask these questions

Comment: I dnt asked any unix based questions here, i want to know "Which is the right place to ask such questions", so there is nothing to downvote my question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can ask *any* type of programming-related question on Stack Overflow. It isn't limited to any specific type of programming questions.

As to why you didn't find any tags relating to Unix programming, I suspect that's because for the majority of questions, the particular operating system in use is irrelevant. The most important thing to tag your questions with is the *language* that you're using, not the operating system. For example, you can write C++ programs in Windows and Unix; both would still be tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

However, you may also be interested in the [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site. It's not necessarily intended for programming-related questions, but rather general questions about the use and abuse of Linux, BSD,
and other Unix-like operating systems. From the [FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Unix and Linux - Stack Exchange is for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - Using or administering a *nix desktop or server
> - The Unix foundation underlying MacOS (but generally *not* frontend application questions)
> - The underlying *nix OS on an embedded system or handheld device (e.g. an Android phone)
> - Shell scripting
> - Applications packaged in *nix distributions *(note: being cross-platform does not disqualify)*
> - UNIX C API and System Interfaces *(within reason)*
>
> then you're in the right place.

Note that *shell scripting* is very much on-topic there (as well as on Stack Overflow), so that's something to consider if you'd prefer to target your questions to a Unix-focused audience.

Comment: To reinforce that, coming from a Unix.SE regular: Unix.SE's audience is mainly Unix users and administrators. The rule of thumb is that if your question is only of interest to developers, we'll send it over to SO.