# "Deleted by…" notice still shows the old unanonymized username

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, deleted-accounts

Here's a user who posted a question on Meta about deleting their account.

[image]

Can you guess the old username? It's the same user who deleted the question.

I believe this should be anonymized as well.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155901/further-anonymize-deleted-accounts-by-changing-the-username-prior-to-deletion?rq=1

Comment: Indeed, that's the same thing, although I consider it a bug :)