# Can't Change my Username But I Want to Delete my account

Tags: support, user-accounts, display-names

I want to delete my account, according to this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

> Due to a [known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155901/further-anonymize-deleted-accounts-by-changing-the-username-prior-to-deletion), you might also want to change your username.

But I can't because I recently changed my username. Is there a way I can make my username something like user8475837 instead of my current name without waiting 30 days?

Comment: Go to another account then where you last change your name. Change it there and apply it to all accounts.

Comment: @Bart I'm getting this error `Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change again in 10 days`

Comment: Hmm, that used to be a valid work-around ...

Comment: @Bart - I remember when that used to work as well, however I think that all changed during an April fool's prank.

Comment: I do believe that if you delete your account, your material generally shows up as `user1021224` (unless your account was deleted prior to some date, October 2012? - somewhere in that range). The linked material in the post states the only place the name will persist is in close and delete votes - seeing as how you cannot cast delete votes, and only flag for closing, this is probably a very small number of posts.

Comment: @Bart that workaround was actually a hole, which we plugged due to abuse of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to - just put the text 'please delete me' somewhere in the 'about me' section of your profile.

It's just a check to ensure that you own the account you're requesting for deletion. As long as we can see you able to change *something* about it, we're good with that.