# Posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site

Tags: discussion, reputation

I was trying to answer a puzzle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/poisoned-iced-tea). But this question is marked protected and says, **posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.**.

I do have 100+ reputation, but still the site is not allowing me to answer. What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you earned 10 reputation **on that site**?

Comment: I have 101 reputation on that site, although I did not earn it but got as an association bonus.