# Username of a deleted user visible on CW posts

Tags: bug, deleted-accounts

It seems to me that if a user makes a post on an SE site, the post is made community wiki, and then the user deletes the account, the post still shows their username. I am not sure if producing examples is OK since some people delete their accounts to dissociate their contributions from their name. Should this behaviour be changed?

Comment: you can see former usernames of deleted users in comments (@-mentions) and close notices as well. Deleting your account doesn't restore your privacy.

Comment: Status by design: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310779/158100

Comment: @rene sure it does not, but we are talking specifically about posts showing the username. For non-CW posts this does not happen so I think this can not be the expected behaviour.

Comment: @dina So we have to wait for a [status-by-design] tag here.